# Why aren't wizards in Kings Cross obvious?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that the kids take the Hogwarts Express from Kings Cross. We also know that many wizards are nearly incapable of choosing Muggle clothes that blend in.

That being the case, why isn't it in the news the twice a year (more, counting the holidays) that hundreds of oddly dressed people descend into Kings Cross?

Why aren't wizards in Kings Cross obvious?

Comment: Never been in Kings Cross, but if it's anything like Amsterdam Centraal then it's probably full of weirdly dressed folks in tourist seasons.

Comment: @Morrigan Wearing nightgowns!??

Comment: sure, why not :)

Comment: I've only been on public transit here in the US, but I quickly picked up on the rule that you do not react to your fellow passengers unless your life is in danger.

Comment: @ForrestVenable And that depends *intensely* on location.  On the Coast Starlight it would be rather rude not to inquisitively engage your fellow passengers. On the east coast overnighters (Broadway Limited) it's more shallow. On the Corridor trains it's unexpected but not entirely unwelcome to engage other passengers, on the commuter trains it's almost rude, and on the NYC subway you'll be considered a scammer and shot dirty looks.

Comment: I would say...magic.

Comment: Maybe they think it's comiccon season?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Muggles would just think they're people with odd fashion sense.

Muggles are generally actively resistant to the suggestion of magic existing.

This is mentioned in the "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them" textbook, in reference to concealing magical creatures from Muggle eyes.

> “Even those Muggles who do notice Porlock droppings or Streeler trails – it would be foolish to suppose that all traces of these creatures can be hidden – appear satisfied with the flimsiest non-magical explanation. <sup>8</sup>” 
> <sub><sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

There's also a book Newt cites about this same phenomenon.

> “8. For a fascinating examination of this fortunate tendency of Muggles, the reader might like to consult The Philosophy of the Mundane: Why the Muggles Prefer Not to Know, Professor Mordicus Egg (Dust & Mildewe, 1963).”
> <sub><sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

If Muggles notice large groups of oddly dressed people hanging around Kings Cross station, they're highly unlikely to think this means wizards exist. Even if they notice that oddly-dressed people show up at the train station as the same times every year, they're likely to think the odd people are probably going to some kind of convention. The Muggle who ran the campsite where wizards were gathering before the Quidditch World Cup thought the wizards were simply foreigners, and that it might be a rally or party.

> “Aye,’ he said thoughtfully. ‘People from all over. Loads of foreigners. And not just foreigners. Weirdos, you know? There’s a bloke walking round in a kilt and a poncho.’
>
> ‘Shouldn’t he?’ said Mr Weasley anxiously.
>
> ‘It’s like some sort of … I dunno … like some sort of rally,’ said Mr Roberts. ‘They all seem to know each other. Like a big party.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 7 (Bagman and Crouch)*</sup></sub>

There may be some Muggles who suspect there's more behind these annual convergences of unusual people at Kings Cross Station, but they're unlikely to be taken seriously and would likely be written off by other Muggles as crazy.

## They did have to be careful to not be noticed going into the wall.

The wizards going through the wall have to time it carefully so the Muggles don’t see.

> “Harry had caught the Hogwarts Express the previous year. The tricky bit was getting onto platform nine and three-quarters, which wasn’t visible to the Muggle eye. What you had to do was walk through the solid barrier dividing platforms nine and ten. It didn’t hurt, but it had to be done carefully so that none of the Muggles noticed you vanishing.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 5 (The Whomping Willow)*</sup></sub>

They have to look carefully to see if any Muggles are watching before deciding to go through the wall.

## However, the Muggles did notice the oddities sometimes.

Once the platform closed during their second year, and Harry and Ron still tried to go through, he made a lot of noise by crashing into it and attracted a bit of attention.

> “A few feet away from it, they broke into a run and –
>
> CRASH.
>
> Both trolleys hit the barrier and bounced backwards. Ron’s trunk fell off with a loud thump, Harry was knocked off his feet, and Hedwig’s cage bounced onto the shiny floor and she rolled away, shrieking indignantly. People all around them stared and a guard nearby yelled, ‘What in blazes d’you think you’re doing?’
>
> ‘Lost control of the trolley,’ Harry gasped, clutching his ribs as he got up. Ron ran to pick up Hedwig, who was causing such a scene that there was a lot of muttering about cruelty to animals from the surrounding crowd.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 5 (The Whomping Willow)*</sup></sub>

Harry was able to make up a believable excuse, but they certainly did attract Muggle attention there.

When Harry took his children to Kings Cross, some people (presumably Muggles since wizards would be used to owls) noticed the owls the family had with them.

> “The commuters stared curiously at the owls as the family wove its way towards the barrier between platforms nine and ten.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Nineteen Years Later (Epilogue)*</sup></sub>

The Muggles probably weren’t thinking “aha, wizards”, but they did see owls as an unusual occurrence.

### A JKR Pottermore writing says the Ministry Obliviates Muggles who see.

In a Pottermore writing, JKR says there are Ministry officials standing by at Kings Cross in case anything goes wrong and Muggles see anything that can’t be easily explained away.

> It was Evangeline Orpington, Minister from 1849-1855, who hit upon the solution of adding a concealed platform at the newly (Muggle) built King’s Cross station, which would be accessible only to witches and wizards. On the whole, this has worked well, although there have been minor problems over the ensuing years, such as witches and wizards who have dropped suitcases full of biting spellbooks or newt spleens all over the polished station floor, or else disappeared through the solid barrier a little too loudly. There are usually a number of plain-clothed Ministry of Magic employees on hand to deal with any inconvenient Muggle memories that may need altering at the start and end of each Hogwarts term. 
> <sub><sup>*[- King’s Cross Station (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/kings-cross-station)*</sup></sub>

So, if the Muggles see anything particularly bad, the Ministry will know and Obliviate whichever Muggles saw the evidence of wizards.

Comment: Just curious.. did someone ever notice their entrance to 9 3/4 wall?

Comment: I'm in a group of thousands of people who dress weirdly once a year, always at the same place. And there's nothing magical going on there. Or is there...

Comment: @Bellatrix LARP/Mythodea

Comment: Well, a few hundreds play wizards at least.

Comment: @Invoker - It's said somewhere that there's Ministry Obliviators / Wizards at hand to stop that kind of thing if it does happen?

Comment: @Malandy Yes, there are. It's mentioned in *Fantastic Beasts* in the same place the quotes from my answer are.

Comment: I wonder though, if there were wizards/witches from the Ministry on hand in case of such a thing, why did none of them notice the wall no longer functioning, and investigate?

Comment: @Irishpanda A writing on Pottermore says there were! *There are usually a number of plain-clothed Ministry of Magic employees on hand to deal with any inconvenient Muggle memories that may need altering at the start and end of each Hogwarts term. - King’s Cross Station (Pottermore)*

Comment: That's what I mean....where were these watchful wizards and witches when Ron and Harry plowed into the wall? Surely at the very least they would notice the commotion near the entry point.

Comment: @Irishpanda Well, the Muggles witnessed chaos but nothing obviously magical, and Harry had said he lost control of the trolley. Maybe they considered the situation not necessary to intervene? In addition, if they did Obliviate some Muggles, if it was after Harry had left, we wouldn’t know about it.